# rank deficient $C$ implies $B'C = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi : I'm reading a paper which has the following statement but doesn't provide the proof.

Suppose I have a matrix $C$ which is $m \times m$ with rank $(m - s)$. Then this implies that there exists another matrix $B$ which is $m \times s$ such that $ B^{\prime} \times C = 0$.

Is there a proof of this somewhere or could someone prove this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the dimension of $\ker C^T$? What can you do with a basis for $\ker C^T$ to get a suitable $B$?

Comment: Hi: I under that the dimension of the basis of ker $C^T$ = s.

Comment: If $C^T v = 0$, then $v^T C = 0$. You can find $s$ linearly independent such $v$'s and stack the $v^T$ on top of each other.

Comment: Hi: Could you tell me the dimensions of v in your comment above. I don't quite follow. Thanks and I'm sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: $C$ is a square $m \times m$ matrix, $v$ is a $m$ dimensional vector (an element of $\ker C^T$).

Comment: Thanks Copper hat. I'll print out what you said and think about it. Is there a way for me to close this thread out. you've answered the question clearly. so even if I don't get it yet, I should still close it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The kernel of $C$ has the dimension $s$ therefore you can find $s$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ as the basis for the kernel of C. You can construct $B$ using these vectors.

Comment: I understand the dimension of the basis of $ker  C^{T} = s$. But I don't see why these s vectors can be used to make B ? Thanks.